# Send JSON and file (image & video) with multipart using axios in Expo React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, expo, multipart

I am trying to send multipart request using axios on a Expo React Native project but after spend a lot of time looking for the correct approach I cannot make it work in Android neither emulator or real device.

My multipart consists on 3 parts: **JSON, image and video**.

**The problem comes with the JSON** since it works just sending image and video alone, without adding JSON part to formData. And it also works if I send JSON as a regular axios post (not multipart), without sending image or video.

**Environment:**

```
"expo": "~46.0.16",
"react-native": "0.69.6",
"axios": "^1.1.0",
```

**My source code:**

```
import mime from 'mime'
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'
import { api } from '../../authentication/infrastructure/api'

const newPost = async (props: Props) => {
const url = '/posts'

  const formData = new FormData()

    const info = {
      title: props.title,
      description: props.description,
      stars: props.stars,
    }
  const infoJSON = JSON.stringify(info)
  const infoBlob =  new Blob([infoJSON], {
      type: 'application/json',
    })

  formData.append('info', infoBlob)
  


  const imageUri = 'file:///' + props.image?.uri.split('file:/').join('')

  const imageObject = {
        name: props.image.uri.split('/').pop(),
        height: props.image.height,
        width: props.image.width,
        type: mime.getType(imageUri),
        uri: imageUri,
      }

  const newVideoUri = 'file:///' + props.video?.uri.split('file:/').join('')

  const videoObject = {
        name: props.video.uri.split('/').pop(),
        height: props.video.height,
        width: props.video.width,
        type: mime.getType(newVideoUri),
        uri: newVideoUri,
      }
  
  formData.append('image', imageObject)
  formData.append('video', videoObject)

  const response = await api.post(url, formData, {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    transformRequest: (data) => data,
  })

  return response
}
```

**What I have tried so far:**

1. **Send JSON as a blob with content-type (above code)**: I get Axios "*Network Error*"
   and the only tip is the *_response* in the request is "*Unrecognized
   FormData part*". I added the "transformRequest" to axios function since I saw it in another stackoverflow question due to axios stringifying formData, but this solution  doesn't work for me.
2. **Send JSON as a string**: many solutions I see in stackoverflow is sending as a string, not a blob, and in spite of I don't get axios error, now I get backend error since I am not sending the content-type 'application-json' and cannot de-serialize it. The error is: *content-type octet-stream is not supported* due to I don't send *content-type: 'application/json'* that's why I tried with the blob approach.
3. **Using fetch instead of axios**: same problems
4. **Comment `FlipperOkhttpInterceptor`**: I saw it in another stackoverflow question since this could be the reason, but doesn't work.
5. **Use FormData from multipart-form data package**: instead of using the native FormData in expo, using the one from package. Doesn't work.

I hope you can help me find a solution that will help all the community since this is a very tricky problem for a lot of users as you can check on the community questions regarding this topic.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

The URI returned by `expo-image-picker` is a reference to a video/image file on device memory but does not contain actual data.

You can enable `base64` and upload generated base64 data.

Comment: I had already base64 enabled, and as I mentioned the problem comes with the JSON, not the files, cause the image and video alone works correctly, but fails when I add JSON to the multipart